# Global Dictionary Between Two Files

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have tried lots of things here but a bit stuck.

I have two python files.

```
----------------------------------

# file_one.py

from file_two import add_value

# Generate some value and pass it over to file_two by calling the function add_value

print add_value("somevalue")

----------------------------------

#file_two.py

myDictionary = {}

def add_value(payload):
    global myDictionary
    # Insert payload with a timestamp in to myDictionary
    myDictionary[payload] = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.now())
    return myDictionary

def some_other_function():

    print myDictionary
```

When I print the Dictionary in file_two.py using another function I only ever get {}. I've tried all kinds of different methods of setting the Dictionary up and not using global etc but I can't get any information out in file_two.

file_one works fine and prints the myDictionary with the correct values.

So I suppose my question is two part. How do I get access to the Dictionary in file_two and where is the data being stored if not in file_two!

Thanks

Edit 1

Some background. file_two is a Django view.py so some_other_function is a browser request. The idea is I will pass the information from the dictionary to the browser to be displayed along with database information.

Could that be the issue? Something to do with the Django package?

I am not actually printing anything. Mostly logger.info......

Edit 2

I solved this by using an SQLite database in folder /dev/shm instead. This is a RAM folder and doesn't persist beyond a reboot which is what I was looking for. An actual SQLite database is easy to ready from multiple different python scripts.

Comment: `dict` is a built-in function/type which returns a dictionary. Name your variable `dict_object` or something like that. Also, in `some_other_function`, it is a good idea to declare `dict_object` a global variable.

Comment: Thanks. dict was just an example. I've changed it now to myDictionary.

Comment: the dict is being stored in fiel_two's namespace. Where do you call some_other_function from?

Comment: file_two is actual Django view.py so some_other_function is a browser request.

Comment: I added a call to `some_other_function` to `file_one.py` and it printed the updated file. You need to give us more details about your implementation. Is that `some_other_function` call in the same process? The same machine?! Suppose you did `import os` and added `os.getpid()` to your prints, would they be the same number?

Comment: You are using django, so wouldn't you use django to store this information so that multiple processes can access it?

Comment: Yes, I thought about this but I want to keep the information in RAM (SD card wear) so I'm not writing it to the database but just wanted to throw it around in a dict. I could use a lightweight RAM database. There are some python ones. But I thought this would be simple :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying Django? If you have multiple workers, global variables like `myDictionary` may not be shared. You are better off storing it in the database or in cache.